# What do I do if I have multiple components?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, factory-pattern

I just started using Autofac. How do I register multiple components? I see this in the QuickStart guide:

```
private static IContainer Container { get; set; }
.
.
.
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<ConsoleOutput>().As<IOutput>();
    builder.RegisterType<TodayWriter>().As<IDateWriter>();
    Container = builder.Build();`
```

What happens if you have multiple components? Does each have their own container to run in? Do I create separate instances for each?

I tried this:

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace DemoApp
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static IContainer ContainerA { get; set; }
    private static IContainer ContainerB { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var builderA = new ContainerBuilderA();
      builderA.RegisterType<ConsoleOutputA>().As<IOutputA>();
      builderA.RegisterType<TodayWriterA>().As<IDateWriterA>();
      ContainerA = builderA.Build();

      var builderB = new ContainerBuilderB();
      builderB.RegisterType<ConsoleOutputB>().As<IOutputB>();
      builderB.RegisterType<TodayWriterB>().As<IDateWriterB>();
      ContainerB = builderB.Build();

      WriteDateA();
      WriteDateB();
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make this cleaner? Also, I am still new to Autofac..Do I still need to provide a design pattern or will autoface handle this for me?

Comment: You need to read _Dependency Injection in .net_ (Mark Seemann), it'll make everything click. But no, you don't want multiple containers. You want one container that builds your entire application object graph in the _composition root_ (that's where you have it, at startup). Typically the _registration_ code would be moved to some extension class, and you'll want to _resolve_ the object graph only once, and _release_ it before you quit the app.

Comment: Note that you can do DI without an IoC container; you'd be newing up all the dependency graph manually and ctor-injecting it into your main application service: an IoC container simply does all the newing-up for you, it doesn't magically know to inject A or B into a service.